# How get android device rotation

Tags: android

I want to get the rotation on x, y and z axis
[image]

I want to get these values

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain Azimuth, Pitch and Roll in this way:

```
 private SensorManager sensorManager;
    ...
    // Rotation matrix based on current readings from accelerometer and magnetometer.
    final float[] rotationMatrix = new float[9];
    SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, null,
        accelerometerReading, magnetometerReading);

    // Express the updated rotation matrix as three orientation angles.
    final float[] orientationAngles = new float[3];
    SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix, orientationAngles);
```

source https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position#java